# Facebook 3.6 Jar is not working in Android

Tags: facebook-android-sdk

I have to use Facebook 3.6 jar instead of Facebook sdk.
While using Facebook 3.6 as jar in my application getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.R$string
at com.facebook.widget.LoginButton.setButtonText(LoginButton.java:596)

But if i am using facebook sdk (Source code) its working fine.

Comment: You can't use the Facebook SDK as a jar, it's not something that's supported since it includes resource files.